# A saying / an expression to say: "most of the problems occure to the weakest people"

Tags: idioms, expressions, proverbs

There is a proverbial sentence in our culture which says:

> - Every obstacle is often on the way of (the weakest / the most poore etc.) people. (literal translation)

**Connotation:** it means usually all the problems / the biggest problems happen to those who are suffering from many other difficulties!

Some founded expressions which seem to be able to make an acceptable sense, but probabely uncommon or old-fashioned is:

> - The weakest go to the wall.

The other expression is:

> - Flies go to the leant hourses. [it is like a translation from another language.]

I'd like to know how would you convey this message through a fixed expreasion or proverbial statement?

Comment: Is this meant to be a positive saying in some way? Or more of a warning?

Comment: None of the @Mile Brockington! Actually, it's said sarcastically about someone's bad luck or an unpeasant happening which occurs to someone.

Answer (score 2):

An expression that comes close to your proverb is:

> The devil take the hindmost

defined by phrases.org.uk as:

**A proverbial phrase indicating that those who lag behind will receive no aid**.

And by Widtionary as:

**everyone should look after their own interests, leaving those who cannot cope to whatever fate befalls them.**

There is a cycle race - with this name - involving a number of circuits in which the last rider to cross the line on each lap falls out of the race.

https://www.phrases.org.uk/meanings/the-devil-take-the-hindmost.html
https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/devil_take_the_hindmost

Comment: Thank you @Tonal Sole, sounds close, but why "take" and not "take**s**"?